# associate() and 1tomany strange behavior

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, orm, one-to-many, laravel-5.3

im using Laravel 5.3 and ive a simple controller with a "store" method, this is the "belongTo" side of the relations. 
The others 2 models contain correctly the "hasMany" function.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $user_id = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()->id;
    if(!Vehicle::where('id', '=', $request->vehicle_id)->exists()){
        return $this->response->error('could_not_create_trip_errore_veicolo', 500);
    }
    if(!Ztl::where('id', '=', $request->ztl_id)->exists()){
        return $this->response->error('could_not_create_trip_errore_ztl', 500);
    }
    $request->request->add(['user_id' => $user_id]);

    $trip = new Trip($request->all());

    //$trip->user()->associate($request->user_id);
    //$trip->vehicle()->associate($request->vehicle_id);
    //$trip->ztl()->associate($request->ztl_id);

    if(true)
    {
        if($trip->save()){

            return $this->response->created();
        }else return $this->response->error('could_not_create_trip', 500);
    }else return $this->response->error('could_not_create_trip_current_user_Error', 500);

}
```

First question is:
 why if comment or uncomment the "associate" method, nothing changes. 
Do I need to put these on the controller or I've not weel understand what is the meaning of this method.

Second:

If I send to my controller some data, using form for testing, what is "required" is the 3 foreign keys.
If I send a number that is not on my other "hasmany" table an error is rise, but if try to insert something like `"2dsksk"` where 2 is a correct ID of the "many" table and then a random string, the ID is taken by the insert as 2, this is correct?
 Validation take just the "correct" number part of the data...the question is, why? and this is secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`associate` just sets the foreign key of the child.  This means you will need to save your model afterwards.

```
 $trip->user()->associate($request->user_id);
 $trip->save();
```

For the second issue, that's likely MySQL truncating the data based on the data type of the column.  If you don't want that to happen, you would likely need to set MySQL to strict mode.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict

Comment: thanks a lot, so about 1) do I need to put just if the records on child model needs to be created?

Comment: Yeah, that `save()` method will run a query so I wouldn't do that unless you are actually making changes to something.  For the second issue, you can validate the issue to solve it.  I'd also suggest setting MySQL to strict mode at least while developing and making sure your foreign key constraints are enforcing the data integrity you need